# How can I uninstall Hotfix remotely with Powershell

Tags: powershell, user-interface, scripting

This what I have so far it brings up a Syntax screen for wusa. I have confirmed that the Trim is working. If I leave out the remote computer name is works on the local computer. I will be adding this to a much larger script just trying to get this working before trying to add it.

<#
.NAME
Template
#>

```
$comp = "Remote Pc Name Goes Here"
$str = $Hotfix_TextBox.Text. Trim("K","B")

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,400)
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$gethotfix                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$gethotfix.text                  = "Get Hotfixes"
$gethotfix.width                 = 120
$gethotfix.height                = 30
$gethotfix.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,81)
$gethotfix.Font                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$removehotfix                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$removehotfix.text                  = "Remove Hotfix"
$removehotfix.width                 = 120
$removehotfix.height                = 30
$removehotfix.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,120)
$removehotfix.Font                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Hotfix_TextBox                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Hotfix_TextBox.Text                   = ""
$Hotfix_TextBox.multiline              = $false
$Hotfix_TextBox.width                  = 174
$Hotfix_TextBox.height                 = 20
$Hotfix_TextBox.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,235)
$Hotfix_TextBox.Font                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
<#
$Trimmed_TextBox                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
#$Trimmed_TextBox.Text                   = "$str"
$Trimmed_TextBox.multiline              = $false
$Trimmed_TextBox.width                  = 174
$Trimmed_TextBox.height                 = 20
$Trimmed_TextBox.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(12,265)
$Trimmed_TextBox.Font                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
#>
$Form.controls.AddRange(@($gethotfix,$removehotfix,$Hotfix_TextBox))

$gethotfix.Add_Click({ GetHotfix })
$removehotfix.Add_Click({ RemoveHotfix })

#region Logic 
function GetHotfix {$Hotfix_TextBox.Text = Get-Hotfix -Computername $comp |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'HotFixID'|
           Out-GridView -Title 'Installed Hotfixes' -PassThru }
#$Hotfix_TextBox.Text. Trim("K","B")    
#$Hotfix_TextBox.Text  = "$str"

function RemoveHotfix{
#$Trimmed_TextBox.Text  = "$str"
$comp = "dus-xtdfed9r386"
 #Uninstall-HotFix -ComputerName $comp
  wusa -computername /$comp | /uninstall | /kb:$str 
}

#endregion

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: wusa does not have a `-computername` parameter. you would need to use `Invoke-Command` to run the command remotely on the remote computer, and then change `$str` to `$using:str`. Also, I'm not sure why you have pipes in there, the command should just be `wusa /uninstall /kb:<KB number>`

Comment: I modified this line "Invoke-Command -Computername $comp wusa  /uninstall /kb:$str" Now I get the following error.  Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/uninstall' also if I add the $using: I get other errors and I know the $str works on the local computer

Comment: I would not have posted this here had I not already poured through both the help file and microsoft documents. I will continue to try different combinations. once I resolve it I will post it back here. Meanwhile if someone has any more constructive advice than  "Read the help file" please do share.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a fiasco. Even when I could get it to work there are many KBs that cannot be removed, as well as we had policies that would not allow us to remove many others. Just not worth the effort. Perhaps someone with less strengent policies in place can do something with this. Have Fun.